# Android: oval shape looks bad

Tags: java, android

I have a button with a oval background and it doesn't look like a perfect circle, I can notice at every distance "breaks" in the circunfrence, this is how it looks

[image]

the background:

```
<shape android:shape="oval"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#7eadb6"/>
<size android:height="80dp"
    android:width="80dp"/>
```

**Edit:** Creating the button

```
static Button theButton1;
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (80, 80);

theButton1 = new Button(getActivity());
theButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
theButton1.setLayoutParams(params);
theButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
theButton1.setTextSize(23);
theButton1.setText(prefs.getString("text1", "").substring(0, 1));
theButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Is this normal? If not how can i fix it?

Note: I have more than one button created like this

Comment: Why Java? Couldn't you just set it in an xml layout?

Comment: Is that what's causing this?

Comment: You could use an image instead.

Comment: I need to set text on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong question leads to wrong answers !!!

By reading your comments, i understand you want to achieve such a thing  at last

[image]

A circle with a text on it .

you can easily reach your aim by using [TextDrawable Library](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable)

Now lets back to your problem, the problem is Surely just because Anti Aliasing. Your problem become even worse on l-dpi devices.

The trick is making a bitmap and pass it as background of your desired view.

```
public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(int dimenSize,int mColor) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(dimenSize, dimenSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    int x = dimenSize;
    int y = dimenSize;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(output, 0.0f, 0.0f, paint);
    paint.setColor(mColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, dimenSize/2, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Now you have a SHARP circle bitmap and can easily use it.

Comment: How do I set the background of a button to a bitmap?

Comment: Drawable circle = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
now you have a drawble. Then use myButton.setBackground(circle); @Kurlicue

Answer (score 1):

This might be an anti-aliasing issue. You have to disable hardware acceleration for it. Try this-

```
<shape android:shape="oval"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>

<solid android:color="#7eadb6"/>
<size android:height="80dp"
    android:width="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

**UPDATE:**

You will also have to set the layer type of button to software.

```
theButton1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

after you set the layout params.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
just update your `Button` in the xml file like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="mytext"
    android:id="@+id/button"
     />
```

and **Keep** in your `activity`:

```
theButton1 = new Button(getActivity());
theButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
theButton1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
theButton1.setTextSize(23);
theButton1.setText(prefs.getString("text1", "").substring(0, 1));
theButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I am adding the buttons programatically by clicking in another button

Comment: do you have to change the `layout_width ` and `layout_width ` programatically or just the background

Comment: I have a lot of buttons to add, how do I bind them to a layout ?

Comment: i think this is a different question than the original.. but please show more from your activity

Comment: you can add `settext`... check my updated answer for other button you do the same

Comment: To do that I need to bind the buttons to a xml file, which I'm not using, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think something is wrong with your implementation.
but try doing it in xml, because it might be causing issues while doing all this at run time. create a button and set its background as your oval shape drawable

```
<Button
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/oval"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="button text here"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with drawable.

> ovelshape.xml

```
  <shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#7eadb6"/>
```

In your XML you need to provide the height & width in dp. And use View instead of Button. I don't no why but it works for me.

```
<View android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ovelshape"/>
```